# access to guest for internal drive partitions

Tags: hard-drive, user-profile, switch-user

In ubuntu guest user can access internal drive partitions only after entering the password of admin but after that guest have access to all drives.

Is their is any way to set system in such a way that guest can access some partitions only not all partition of drive?

Comment: Please edit the question and be more specific. Are you talking about external USB drives, or internal partitions, such as the Windows partition?

Comment: i am talking about partitions of internal drive

Comment: please tell me if their is any way to lock specific partitions of internal hard disk

Answer (score 1):

I got the solutions for managing permissions by installing some software

I have tried **mount manager** and **storage device manager** for managing the partitions.

Both applications are good but **storage device manager** is easy while **mountmanager** have more functionalities.

those applications don't provide access to guest users but provide access to specific partitions to other user accounts.

Comment: Will you elaborate the answer describing the process?